# How can I connect dozens of sensors of the same address to one i2c bus?

Tags: arduino, sensor, i2c

I want to connect dozens of i2c sensors of the same type to one arduino. Reprogramming the address is unfortunately not possible for all the sensors. I will illustrate what I mean with the following sketch:
[image]

As  can be seen, the sensors of type A, B and C are repeated many times. I want to have something like an address chip for which I can freely program an address, and when my Arduino talks to one of them, it reads sensors A, B and C and returns those values to the Arduino as if the Arduino had talked to one sensor. Note that A, B and C are i2c sensors, but changing their addresses is not possible.

Is there something like an "address chip" that can do this? Or is there an other possible solution?

**UPDATE:** Long lines is a need, i.e. I'll need ~100m. It's for measurements around a large area, something like humidity (DHT22) & light (not decided which one yet)

Comment: 'I2C multiplexer' is the google search you're looking for.

Comment: Another term used is I2C (and sometimes SMB) address translator.

Comment: What are the actual devices?

Comment: @brhans, even an I2 multiplexer (or 2)  is going to have trouble with "dozens" of slave devices.

Comment: @ThePhoton a PCA9547 will multiplex 8 slaves by itself and you can have 8 PCA9547's together on 1 bus. 64 slaves counts as dozens in my book.

Comment: I²C is not designed for long bus lines. Unless your sensors are physically very close (like on the same PCB) you will need something else (RS485, CAN,..) as a bus in between.

Comment: Yes long lines is a need, i.e. I'll have a ~100m. It's for measurements around a large area, something like humidity (DHT22) & light (not decided which one yet).

Comment: I2C 20-30 devices typically <10m depending on bus capacitance.  Usually as Turbo says on the same PCB.

Answer (score 3):

Go for PCA9544 or any similar I2C Multiplexer.